# how to list top following persons accounts along with the rest of them

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel-4

i'm working on a medical project. in that a user can follow and unfollow doctors. so i uses a table called `followers` in which the `user_id` and followed `doctor_id` and followed `date time`. if a user unfollow a doctor that entry will be deleted from the table `followers`.

so my issue is, after the user logged in, in his dashboard corner side i have to show top doctors for you. in that list i need to display max 5 doctors . At present i'm able to list down 5 doctors from the `doctors` table. but i need to add the followed doctors that this particular user following. if the user is not following anyone then just a list of 5 from doctors table.

```
$ds = Doctors::where('status','=',1)->orderBy('verified','desc')->take(5)->get();
```

i know i have to do join. but i'm confused about how i will do it. please help me to figure this out.

Comment: Please answer your own question and post how you solved it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

ok.. i solved it by myself using this query

```
Doctors::join('followers','doctors.doctor_id','=','followers.doctor_id')->where‌​('doctors.doctor_status','=',1)->where('followers.patient_id','=',$patient_id)->t‌​ake(5)->get();
```